# Oracle SQL join having exclusive row matching with non-key columns

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I would like to join these two tables, but I want to make each ID+MODEL has an exclusive color.

```
Table 1                   Table 2
PART   Model              PART   COLOR  
--------------            ------------
1      XXX                1      RED
1      YYY                1      BLUE
2      ZZZ                1      YELLOW
```

TO-BE

```
PART     MODEL     COLOR
1        XXX       RED
1        YYY       YELLOW
```

In the above example, 1 + XXX has RED, so RED will be joined to any other row.
Is there a cool trick to do this? I searched everywhere but I cannot come up with a solution besides storing results into a table.

Thank you!

Comment: Why not make 1 XXX and 1 YYY both be RED? Do you need an *injective* function (meaning different models must have different colors)? What if that is not possible - what if there are more models than available colors? The problem itself doesn't make 100% sense without more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fail to se the logic behind the join condition, except that for each `part` create one random `model`+`color` combination.

We can do that by introducing an unique id for each `part` with everyone's favorite analytic function [`row_number`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions170.htm#SQLRF06100) and then use that in the join.

Note that because `partition by part order by part` the parts are sorted "randomly" (i.e. the database engine decises the order not you).

```
with
models(part, model) as (
  select 1, 'XXX' from dual union all
  select 1, 'YYY' from dual union all
  select 2, 'ZZZ' from dual
),
models2(part, rn, model) as (
  select
   part
  ,row_number() over (partition by part order by part) as rn
  ,model
  from models
),
colors(part, color) as (
  select 1, 'RED'    from dual union all
  select 1, 'BLUE'   from dual union all
  select 1, 'YELLOW' from dual
),
colors2(part, rn, color) as (
  select
   part
  ,row_number() over (partition by part order by part) as rn
  ,color
  from colors
)
select
 models2.part
,models2.model
,colors2.color
from models2
inner join colors2 on colors2.part = models2.part
                  and colors2.rn = models2.rn
;
```

**Results**

```
PART MODEL      COLOR
---- ---------- ----------
   1 XXX        RED
   1 YYY        YELLOW
```

Answer (score 0):

No one here can work out your logic: perhaps this indicates this is best modelled by adding rows to a third table that references the first two: e.g. here's a sketch in standard SQL:

```
  CREATE TABLE Table1
  (
   PART INT NOT NULL,
   MODEL CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
   UNIQUE ( MODEL, PART )
  );

  CREATE TABLE Table2
  (
   PART INT NOT NULL,
   COLOR CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
   UNIQUE ( COLOR, PART )
  );

  CREATE TABLE ToBe
  (
   PART INT NOT NULL,
   MODEL CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
   COLOR CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
   FOREIGN KEY ( MODEL, PART )
      REFERENCES Table1 ( MODEL, PART ),
   FOREIGN KEY ( COLOR, PART )
      REFERENCES Table2 ( COLOR, PART ),
   UNIQUE ( COLOR, MODEL, PART )
  );
```